# iPhone4 different behavior for different signing identities

Tags: iphone, ios, code-signing

We have an app, that we try to distribute. We also have two different signing identities. When signing with one of them, everything works fine on iPhone4. Using the other one, the app can't be installed on iPhone4 with the config utility giving the error: 'This application does not support this device's CPU type'. On iPhone5, installation with both identities works fine, too. Anyone already experienced this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signing identity shouldn't cause any architecture related issues like the on you describe: 'This application does not support this device's CPU type'.

Make sure that you set "Build Active Architectures Only" (Project > Build Settings > Build Active Architectures Only) to NO and try again.

The following scenario could cause the problem:

"Build Active Architectures Only" is set to YES, you've connected an iPhone 5 via USB which is  selected as launch destination in the scheme selection menu.

The IPA file created with these settings will run on armv7s devices only (currently iPhone 5 and iPad 4).

Connecting and selecting an iPhone 4 would produce an armv7 IPA which should run on armv7s machines too. (Cause of backwards compatibility.)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Target>Build Settings> Architecture, and check the "valid architectures" value it should have armv7 and armv7s if you want it to run in both iPhone 5 and iPhone 4

Comment: In other words, it's not the signing identity. :)

Comment: @MarcusAdams yep :), also make sure Build Active Architecture Only is set to NO and Architectures includes armv7 and armv7s

Comment: Nope, that's not it. We have both 'Architectures' as well as 'Valid Architectures' set so. Any other ideas?